# Loop through filenames without eval

Tags: shell-script, wildcards, eval

In a shell script, if we want to loop over certain filenames, which we would get by shell globbing, as for example all MKV-files in all sub-directories starting with string "Example" – how can we do this without using `eval`?

E.g. while the following script does the loop

```
#!/usr/local/bin/zsh

for i in /media/mybook/Example*/; do;
  t="ls \"$i\"*.mkv" 
  s=$(eval $t)
  echo $s
done
```

is there a way to get rid of the `eval`?

Comment: Regarding you recent edit: Any chance that we get to see what you're actually trying to do so that we can modify our solutions?

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused why you would want to use `eval` here. You could just write `s=$(ls "$i"*.mkv)`. But [calling `ls` is pointless and would mangle file names](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). Just iterate over the files normally.

```
for dir in /media/mybook/Example*/; do;
  if ! [ -d "$dir" ]; then continue; fi
  for file in "$dir"/*.mkv; do
    if ! [ -e "$file" ]; then continue; fi
    echo "$file"
  done
done
```

Note how `"$dir"` is within double quotes (so that any special characters such as spaces in the directory name remain as they are), but the `*` is outside the quotes so it's treated as a wildcard.

The lines with `continue` are there to skip the special case where the wildcard matches nothing. In sh, when a wildcard doesn't match, it's left as is, and so `for` sees a list of names with one element which is literally `/media/mybook/Example*/` (for the outer loop). Some shells (ksh, bash, zsh) have a way to avoid this, for example in bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for dir in /media/mybook/Example*/; do;
  for file in "$dir"/*.mkv; do
    echo "$file"
  done
done
```

If you're just processing the files and don't need to do anything for the directories, there's no point in having two nested loops.

```
for dir in /media/mybook/Example*/*.mkv; do
  if ! [ -e "$file" ]; then continue; fi
  echo "$file"
done
```

All these snippets act on files inside the `Example*` directories themselves, no in their subdirectories. If you want to traverse the directories recursively, see [Kusalananda's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/498853).

Answer (score 0):

Using `find`:

```
find /media/mybook/Example*/ -type f -name '*.mkv' -print
```

Add `-maxdepth 1` before `-type f` if you don't want to recurse into subdirectories.

Or just a straight shell loop (will not work if there are many thousands of files), and assuming you only want to look in the first subdirectory level:

```
for pathname in /media/mybook/Example*/*.mkv; do
    printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
done
```

If you want to recurse down into subdirectories, using `zsh` or `bash` with its `globstar` shell option set (again, will not work for several thousand files):

```
for pathname in /media/mybook/Example*/**/*.mkv; do
    printf '%s\n' "$pathname"
done
```

Related:

- [Why *not* parse `ls` (and what do to instead)?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985)

---

To *do* something with the pathnames:

With `find`:

```
find /media/mybook/Example*/ -type f -name '*.mkv' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        # Use "$pathname" here
    done' sh {} +
```

... where `sh -c` could obviously be changed to `bash -c` or `zsh -c` if you need to use any special features of these shells.

Related:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

With a shell loop:

```
for pathname in /media/mybook/Example*/*.mkv; do
    # Use "$pathname" here
done
```

---

Also related:

- [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/321697)